# Text Input and Numerical Output issue for Exam Schedule Predictor

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, regression

I'm working on a model that would predict an exam schedule for a given course and term. My input would be the term and the course name, and the output would be the date. I'm currently done with the data cleaning and preprocessing step, however, I can't wrap my head around a way to make a model whose input is two strings and the output is two numbers (the day and month of exam). One approach that I thought of would be encoding my course names, and writing the term as a binary list. I.E input: encoded(course), [0,0,1] output: day, month. and then feeding to a regression model. 
I hope someone who's more experienced could tell me a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Before I start answering your question: 
*/rant* 
I know this sounds dumb and doesn't really help your question, but ***why* are you using Neural Networks for this?!**
To me, this seems like the classical case of "everybody uses ML/AI in their area, so now I have to, too!" (which is completely not true) 
*/rant over*

For string-like inputs, there exist several methods to encode these; choosing the right one might depend on your specific task. As you have a very "simple" (and predictable) input - i.e., you know in advance that there might not be any new/unseen course titles during testing/inference, or you do not need contextual/semantic information, you can resort to something like scikit-learn's [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html), which will turn it into different classes.

Alternatively, you could also throw a more heavy-weight encoding structure at the problem, that embeds the values in a matrix. Most DL frameworks offer some [form of internal function for this](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=embed#torch.nn.Embedding), which basically requires you to pass an unique index for your input data, and actively learns some `k`-dimensional embedding vector for this. Intuitively, these embeddings correspond to a semantic or topical direction. If you have for example 3-dimensional embeddings, the first one could represent "social sciences course", the other one "technical courses", and the third for "seminar".

Of course, this is just a simplification of it, but helps imagining how it works.

For the output, predicting a specific date is actually a really good question. As I have personally never predicted dates myself, I can only recommend tips by other users. A nice answer on dates (as input) is given [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14634/how-to-encode-date-as-input-in-neural-network).
If you can sacrifice a little bit of accuracy in the result, predicting the *calendar week* in which the exam is happening might be a good idea. Otherwise, you could simply treat it as two regressed values, but you might end up with invalid combinations (i.e. "negative days/months", or something like "31st February".

Depending on how much training data of high quality you have, results might vary quite heavily. Lastly, I would again recommend you to overthink whether you actually need a neural network for this task, or whether there are simpler metrics to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Create dummy variables or use RandomForest. They accept text input and numerical output.